# Imported packaged files ".key .numbers .pages" from iCloud using UIDocumentMenuViewController are not opening in UIWebView

Tags: numbers, icloud, keynote, iwork, uidocumentmenuvc

Hi I am trying to display a packaged file say .key/.pages/.numbers file to user in a UIWebView but I cant. The keynote file was created using a Keynote app from my iPad recently. I imported that file to my app using UIDocumentMenuViewController from iCloud. I tried to look into the file attributes and it turn out that the file imported is actually a "directory" not single file. Inside, it has some contents. Can anybody tell me how to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  iWork files are zipped bundles but for some reason importing from iCloud unzips the contents first, whearas copying from the app directly via Open in ... from Number (or Pages or Keynote) works perfectly.

So what you need to do is test if the result of import is a directory, and if so zip the directory into a single file and keep the correct file extension (.number pages or .key).

This seems like a hack but it works and is best workaround I've been able to find

In Swift you can use SSZipArchive as an easy way to zip a directory